# UMS.sh (run as service) on Ubuntu 14.04 won't read configuration file

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, services

I'm trying to get my ubuntu 14.04 to run universal media server so I can stream movies to my ps3 (lowest firmware 4.55 unfortunately - unjailbreakable).

After much research on the net I was able to get it running as a service, `/etc/init.d/UMS.sh`, the other files are in `/usr/ums` folder. These include the `UMS.conf` configuration file, `UMS.sh` file, and `ums.jar` file and all the others.

I've used `cream` (`gedit` has issues with creating these temporary files that I need to delete later) to edit `UMS.conf` file.

I'm trying to get it to run on a specific port and have a IP whitelist so everyone on the network won't be able to access my stuff.

So I made the changes on `UMS.conf` file, loaded it a few times to double check that the changes saved - they did - but when I do:

```
   service UMS.sh start
```

UMS will start but with all default configurations.

Please help. I'm new to Ubuntu so also please walk me through. I can provide the script `/etc/init.d/UMS.sh` if that helps, but please tell me how to paste here, I tried and the # made stuff bold.

UPDATE: With help from Letizia's comment, here's the script for

> '/etc/init.d/UMS.sh'

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ums
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts UMS program.
# Description:       Java Upnp Media Server dedicated to PS3
### END INIT INFO

#set -x

# Author: Papa Issa DIAKHATE <paissad@gmail.com>
#
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="Universal Media Server"
NAME=UMS.sh
UMS_PROFILE=/etc/$NAME
DAEMON=/usr/ums/$NAME
DAEMON_OPTS="console"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
UMS_START=1 # Wether to start or not UMS ver at boot time.
DODTIME=30  # Time to wait for the server to die, in seconds.
            # If this value is set too low you might not
            # let the program to die gracefully and 'restart' will not work

test -x $DAEMON || exit 1

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Include ums defaults if available
if [[ -f "/etc/default/$NAME" ]] ; then
        . /etc/default/$NAME
fi

# May we run the init.d script ?
[[ $UMS_START = 1 ]] || exit 1

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Some color codes
txtred=$'\e[0;31m' # Red
txtylw=$'\e[0;33m' # Yellow
txtrst=$'\e[0m'    # Text Reset
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
warnout(){
    echo >&2 -e ""$txtylw"Warning:$txtrst $1"
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
running(){
    pid=`pgrep -f 'java .*ums.jar.*'`
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_start(){
    running && { warnout "$NAME is already running !"; exit 0; }
    echo "Starting $DESC : $NAME"
    UMS_PROFILE="$UMS_PROFILE" start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --oknodo \
        --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS

}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_stop(){
    running || { warnout "$NAME is NOT running !"; exit 0; }   
    local countdown="$DODTIME"
    echo -e "Stopping $DESC : $NAME \c "
    kill -9 $pid
    while running; do
        if (($countdown >= 0)); then
            sleep 1; echo -n .;
            ((--countdown))
        else
            break;
        fi
    done
    echo
    # If still running, then try to send SIGINT signal
    running && { \
        echo >&2 "Using kill -s SIGINT instead"; \
        echo >&2 "If you see this message again, then you should increase the value of DODTIME in '$0'."; \
        kill -2 $pid; \
    }

    if [ -e "/usr/share/ums/debug.log" ]; then
    count=9
    while [ $count -ge 1 ]
    do
    if [ -e "/usr/share/ums/debug.log.$count" ]; then
        plus=$((count+1))
        mv "/usr/share/ums/debug.log.$count" "/usr/share/ums/debug.log.$plus"
    fi
        count=$((count-1))
    done
    if [ -e "/usr/share/ums/debug.log" ]; then
        mv "/usr/share/ums/debug.log" "/usr/share/ums/debug.log.1"
    fi
    fi

    return 0
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_force-stop(){
    running || { warnout "$NAME is NOT running !"; exit 0; }   
    echo "Stopping $DESC : $NAME"
    kill -9 $pid
    if [ -e "/usr/share/ums/debug.log" ]; then
    count=9
    while [ $count -ge 1 ]
    do
    if [ -e "/usr/share/ums/debug.log.$count" ]; then
        plus=$((count+1))
   mv "/usr/share/ums/debug.log.$count" "/usr/share/ums/debug.log.$plus"
    fi
       count=$((count-1))
    done
    if [ -e "/usr/share/ums/debug.log" ]; then
   mv "/usr/share/ums/debug.log" "/usr/share/ums/debug.log.1"
    fi
    fi
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_status(){
    echo -n " * $NAME is "
    ( running || { echo "NOT running "; exit 0; } )
    ( running && { echo "running (PID -> $(echo $pid))"; exit 0; } )
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
case "$1" in

    start|stop|force-stop|status)
        do_${1}
        ;;
    restart|reload)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;
    force-restart|force-reload)
        do_force-stop
        do_start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|force-stop|restart|force-restart|reload|force-reload|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: You could post your script on http://pastebin.com/ and update your question with url or you could post it in your question, select all the line and use `<$>` to mark those lines as code.

Comment: Great, thank you! I just updated the question with the script.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you used the same script that I did to install UMS. I ran into this same issue and found a way to fix it. The script creates a link in /etc that points to a file in /root that doesn't exist. If you do a ls -l on /etc you should see something like:

```
UMS.sh < /root/.config/UMS.conf
```

but the script never actually creates that file, probably doesn't have the permissions too. So what I did was delete that link and create a new one pointing to the config file in /usr/ums/

```
sudo rm /etc/UMS.sh
sudo ln -s /usr/ums/UMS.conf /etc/UMS.sh
```

This ended up working for me and now I can just edit the UMS.conf file to make any changes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, the correct fix is this:

- run UMS.sh as root; it will create the profile /root/.config/UMS
- edit the init script /etc/init.d/ums and put the profile path right: UMS_PROFILE=/root/.config/UMS/